# Ionic + Auth0 hangs when emulating on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

I followed @mgonto 's [Adding Auth to your Ionic App in 5 minutes](http://ionicframework.com/blog/authentication-in-ionic/).  It works great in my browser but when I "ionic emulate ios" it just hangs after I try to authenticate with Facebook (see screenshot).

Any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot of Auth0 hanging during iOS emulation]

Comment: Run `ionic emulate ios -l -c -s` which will use live reload in the emulator and also output error logs to the command line so you can see what is going on. You need to get an error message to see what might be happening.

Comment: When I run that command, I get the following errors "0 246540   log deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
1 246544 log Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady." This happens before I even click the Facebook button.  I'm assuming this is what's causing Auth0 to hang.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you have InAppBrowser plugin correctly installed. You can install it by doing: `ionic plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

Comment: The InAppBrowser is correctly installed and the <feature name="InAppBrowser"></feature> tags have been added to my config.xml.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hey, besides the <feature>, did you add the `<param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />` inside? That might be the problem. From what I see, the error is that the Popup isn't openning. It has something to do with the InAppBrowser plugin not working for some reason. Try removing the InAppBrowser plugin from Cordova's cache and reinstalling.

Comment: @mgonto...yup, the <param> tags are inside the <feature> tags.  In my second comment (above), I indicated I get the error "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds"...do you feel this is not significant?  You mention clearing the InAppBrowser from Cordova's cache - do I just delete the org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser from the plugin directory and reinstall? Or, is there a Cordova cache file somewhere?

Comment: You might want to try and generate a new project today, and check what the CLI tool sets up and see what is different in the config.xml.

Comment: @hugo: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having a similar problem where it works in the browser but not on device or in iOS simulator.

Comment: @jmcopeland did you ever figure out how to get past this issue? I'm being ailed by a similar circumstance.